# How to change the color of an output text based on selected picklist value

Tags: picklist, css, rerender

I have a picklist field.

When the field value is `x`, the color should be yellow. And when its value is `y` its color should be orange.

How to change the color of the output text based on picklist values in Salesforce?
How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` formula on the output text's `style` attribute, like the following:

```
<apex:outputText
          value="{!Account.AccountSource}"
          style="color: {!CASE(Account.AccountSource, 'Web', '#f0f', '#000')}">
</apex:outputText>
```

This will turn the text pink when "Web" is selected as the Account Source.

Please remember to add a `actionSupport` tag to your picklist element so that the page can rerender when the option is changed, like this:

```
<apex:inputField id="field1" value="{!Account.AccountSource}">
    <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" rerender="mainform"/>
</apex:inputField>
```

Comment: Why are you putting #000 there? it is appearing in black color and color is not changed.

Comment: The first argument of the case formula is the field to be evaluated, followed by the value to be compared and the output to that specific value. The last argument (#000) is the default when the value does not match any of the previously specified values.